# Quartz.NET + SQLite Jobstore throwing JobPersistenceException

Tags: c#, sqlite, quartz.net, system.data.sqlite

When adding or removing a job to/from the scheduler, Quartz sporadically throws a JobPersistenceException (following a preceding SQLiteException).

Things that seem noteworthy:

- Quartz.NET 2.01 + System.Data.SQLite 1.0.66 (<s>both latest version at time of writing</s> just noticed that there is a binary package for SQLite 1.0.82 available)
- the exception is also thrown if there is currently no job/trigger beeing executed (i am monitoring the Quartz listeners)
- the Jobs are manually added from UI context (i require about 10-20 repetitions to cause the error but it seems totally random)
- <s>Everything seems to be running fine (multiple jobs, parallel execution, persistance after application restart) as long as i don't touch AddJob()/DeleteJob()</s>  After extended testing i am sure its not related to adding/removing jobs. The db locking/access problems are a general problem.

Is there any recommended procedure i am not aware that must be followed when adding/deleting jobs?

Is there anything wrong with my ISchedulerFactory configuration? (see below)

**Supplemental**

- I tried using System.Data.SQLite 1.0.82 which made things worse. I get "SQLite error (5): database is locked" almost constantly as soon as Quartz is executing a Job.
- Quartz.NET list System.Data.SQLite 1.0.56 as supported db provider so one might expect problems using a newer version. However, i don't consider going back from 1.0.66 as an option since there were lots of improvements/fixes IIRC.
- I took a look at the development trunk of Quartz.NET between the 2.0.1 release revision (624) and current head revision (669). There seem to be no related fixes.
- I suspect that its a System.Data.SQLite issue. I stumbled over several posts (concerning different SQLite versions) mentioning that there might be some issues with internal disposing of resources, keeping the DB file locked.

**Supplemental 2**

For now, I gave up on this. I tried a lot of things, but development has to go on. I switched to another database type (Firebird) which so far seems to work fine with Quartz.

If somebody gets this working i would love to hear about it anyway.

-

Exception details:

Quartz.JobPersistenceException: "Couldn't commit ADO.NET transaction. The database file is locked\r\ndatabase is locked"

Stack

```cs
bei Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CommitConnection(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder cth, Boolean openNewTransaction)
bei Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock(String lockName, Func`2 txCallback)
bei Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX.ExecuteInLock(String lockName, Func`2 txCallback)
bei Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.RemoveJob(JobKey jobKey)
bei Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.DeleteJob(JobKey jobKey)
bei Quartz.Impl.StdScheduler.DeleteJob(JobKey jobKey)
```

InnerException SQLiteException: "The database file is locked\r\ndatabase is locked"

Stack

```cs
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.Commit()
bei Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CommitConnection(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder cth, Boolean openNewTransaction)
```

The source of the exception is "cth.Transaction.Commit();" in this Quartz.NET method.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Commit the supplied connection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cth">The CTH.</param>
/// <param name="openNewTransaction">if set to <c>true</c> opens a new transaction.</param>
/// <throws>JobPersistenceException thrown if a SQLException occurs when the </throws>
protected virtual void CommitConnection(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder cth, bool openNewTransaction)
{
    CheckNotZombied(cth);

    if (cth.Transaction != null)
    {
        try
        {
            IsolationLevel il = cth.Transaction.IsolationLevel;
            cth.Transaction.Commit();
            if (openNewTransaction)
            {
                // open new transaction to go with
                cth.Transaction = cth.Connection.BeginTransaction(il);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new JobPersistenceException("Couldn't commit ADO.NET transaction. " + e.Message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i create the ISchedulerFactory:

```cs
public static ISchedulerFactory CreateSQLiteSchedFactory(SQLiteConnection sqlConn, string tablePrefix) {
    // db provider hinzufügen
    var metaData = new DbMetadata();
    metaData.AssemblyName = "System.Data.SQLite,Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139";
    metaData.BindByName = true;
    metaData.CommandBuilderType = typeof(SQLiteCommandBuilder);
    metaData.CommandType = typeof(SQLiteCommand);
    metaData.ConnectionType = typeof(SQLiteConnection);
    metaData.ExceptionType = typeof(SQLiteException);
    metaData.ParameterDbType = typeof(TypeAffinity);
    metaData.ParameterDbTypePropertyName = "DbType";
    metaData.ParameterNamePrefix = "@";
    metaData.ParameterType = typeof(SQLiteParameter);
    metaData.UseParameterNamePrefixInParameterCollection = true;
    DbProvider.RegisterDbMetadata("SQLite-1066", metaData);

    // konfiguration für factory erstellen
    NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
    properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler";
    properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = tablePrefix;
    properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";

    properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

    properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = sqlConn.ConnectionString;
    properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SQLite-1066";

    // factory erzeugen
    return new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
}
```

The SQLiteConnection is created with connectionstring similar to "Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;" and all the quartz tables are initialized using the supplied SQL script

Answer (score 2):

You have to set this one to true in the properties:

```
properties["quartz.jobStore.txIsolationLevelSerializable"] = "true";
```

Comment: Do you have any additional information (source?) why this should resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error is most likely to be because of multiple concurrent writes on the SQLite db, sqlite can accept multiple read-only connections only, but the can't accept simultaneous writes!

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: Then the question would be why there are any concurrent writes when adding/removing jobs and what can i do to minimize the possibility. Parallel job execution is (from what i can tell) handled just fine. But yes, the best guess so far is that Quartz does not properly handle SQLite write concurrency requirments in all cases.